# ffplay cannot position multiple players at different locations on the screen

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

We would like to use ffplay for monitoring live streamed video, instead of VLC. We are hitting some limitations. DO we know work arounds? The first issue is that we cannot position ffplay's windows at different locations on the screen via command line params. We've tried options on the command line of -x,-y,-top,-left,-w and -h, -width and -height. It appears that only -x and -y are recognized by ffplay as valid Options, regardless of the corresponding values assigned to each option. Also, -x seems to be the "width" of the player, and -y the "height" as opposed to the x and y location of a corner of the player on the screen. The other options seem to return unrecognized option. Is there a standard set of options available on all builds / OS download releases that will work to allow us to place the players around the screen? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Current ffplay recognizes `left` and `top` for position of top-left corner of display window, measured in pixels from top-left corner of display. Thee were added in v4.1. And `x` and y` are for width and height of display window, and are older options.